# Controling attribute change in JTextPane

Tags: java, user-interface, attributes

I need to make possible for user to change the text color on a button click. This is fine when there is selection - the text will change it's color. However when selection length is 0, when I only have the caret, nothing will be changed, and that is perfectly normal.

However, user will expect that the next character he types in at that location after button click will have changed color, which doesn't happen.

Try opening a MS Word document, type some text, click RIGHT BEFORE OR RIGHT AFTER A WORD. Don't click within the word itself. Now change color of the text - nothing (visible) will happen. Continue typing - the color of typed text is the one you changed it to.

Now try to do the same with the program below and the color won't change. How can I make it happen?

Here's a SSCCE, for your convenience, but it's just normal Java 7, no special stuff:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Style;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;


public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame a = new JFrame("Test");
        a.setSize(600, 900);
        a.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        a.getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(a.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        final JTextPane b = new JTextPane();
        b.addFocusListener(new FocusListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0)
            {
                b.repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0)
            {
                b.repaint();
            }
        });

        StyleContext context = new StyleContext();
        final Style styleA = context.addStyle("A", null);
        final Style styleB = context.addStyle("B", null);


        StyleConstants.setForeground(styleA, Color.BLUE);
        StyleConstants.setForeground(styleB, Color.RED);            

        try
        {
            b.getStyledDocument().insertString(0, "blablablablabla", styleA);
        }

        catch (BadLocationException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JButton c = new JButton("click me");
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
            {
                b.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(b.getSelectionStart(), b.getSelectionEnd() - b.getSelectionStart(), styleB, true);
                b.grabFocus();
            }
        });

        a.getContentPane().add(b);
        a.getContentPane().add(c);

        a.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Here's a SSCCE, for your convenience` - it would have been more convenient if you posted the SSCCE with your original question hours ago. You have asked enough questions in the forum to know that a SSCCE should be posted with all your questions to show what you are doing when you encounter a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for a working demo that does what you want. That is the default Actions in the editor kit work the way you would expect them to. So I would suggest you look at the source code of the `StyledEditorKit` and look at the `BoldAction` to get an idea of how this should be done.

I've never used StyleContext so I'm not exactly sure how they work. I use a SimpleAttributSet, something like:

```
SimpleAttributeSet red = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(red, Color.RED);
```

Then to change the attribute I would use:

```
textPane.getStyledDocument().setCharacterAttributes(??, ??, red, false);
```

Now, this is the part I haven't done before, but basically you need to change the "input attributes" as well. I think the code is something like:

```
MutableAttributeSet inputAttr = textPane.getInputAttributes();
inputAttr.addAttributes(red);
```

Again, check with the source code from the StyledEditorKit (I simplified the code so it may not be exact).